# Setting up Bluetooth on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Tags: wireless, bluetooth, vmware

I have a VM, and I was going around through the settings, and tried to set up the bluetooth. However, I none of my devices were connecting. Is this just becuase it is a Linux device and they may not be compatible? The devices in question are mpow flames, and also skullcandy hesh 3. As mentioned, I have Ubuntu 18.04 LTS running on my VM.

Comment: Do you have a laptop? Do you have windows 10 installed? Do you have  Ubuntu 18.04 in VM on Windows 10? How did you try to setup ubuntu with  bluetooth devices? Did you use command line?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the manufacturer of the BT chipset, it may not work at all with Hyper-V passthrough. BCM2070A0 chipsets don't like it at all. If you could share what chipset the BT in the computer uses, I may be able to help.

(posting as an answer because I can't comment)